# How to prove this inequality : $(x^a+y^a)^{\frac1{a}}>(x^b+y^b)^{\frac1{b}} \, ; x>0,\ y>0;\ 0<a<b$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that when $\displaystyle x>0,\ y>0;\ 0<a<b$

$$\displaystyle(x^a+y^a)^{\frac1{a}}>(x^b+y^b)^{\frac1{b}}$$

Comment: Oops, dont know why I write as integral..

Answer (score 4):

A first change of variable $x_0=x^a$ and $y_0=y^a$ shows that this is equivalent to
$$
x_0^p+y_0^p<(x_0+y_0)^p
$$
for all $x_0>0, y_0>0$, where $p=b/a>1$.

A second change of variable $t=x_0/y_0$ yields the equivalent property
$$
1+t^p<(1+t)^p
$$
for all $t>0$.

Now a straightforward study of the function 
$$
f(t)=(1+t)^p-1-t^p
$$
shows that the latter is positive on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff From the assumptions, $p$ is any real number greater than $1$.

Comment: Oh, missed that. I'll clean this.

Comment: nice one +1, can one also use the fact that, by the way the OP has defined, both LHS and RHS of the inequality are both proper norms in variables $(x,y)$, and thus by the property of norms, this follows?

Comment: @dineshdileep Thanks. When $a<1$, the lhs is not a norm. Likewise for the rhs when $b<1$. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space. Now when $1\leq a<b$, these are indeed norms. But I don't know which property of norms could help you prove the inequality.

Comment: I mean for $b\geq a\geq 1$, we have that $||.||_b\leq ||.||_a$, I can't find a proof though now.